# I am Unable to go forward to the circular progress indicator on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

This is the code I have written for my home screen of the app. There is not any error but when I run the program, it just stops on the indicator. The screen doesn't go forward to the entire code and screen. I don't know what happened there.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: CustomAppBar(
      title: '',
    ),
    body: BlocBuilder<SwipeBloc, SwipeState>(
      builder: (context, state) { 
             if (state is SwipeLoading) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (state is SwipeLoaded) {
          var userCount = state.users.length;
          return Column(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onDoubleTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/users',
                    arguments: state.users[0]);
                },
                child: Draggable<User>(
                data: state.users[0],
                  child: UserCard(user: state.users[0]),
                  feedback: UserCard(user: state.users[0]),
                  childWhenDragging: (userCount > 1) ?
                    UserCard(user: state.users[1]): Container(),
                  onDragEnd: (drag) {
                    if (drag.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0) {
                      context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                        ..add(SwipeLeft(user: state.users[0]));
                      print('Swiped left');
                    } else {
                      context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                        ..add(SwipeRight(user: state.users[0]));
                      print('Swiped right');
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Just able to see this screen. This screen doesn't go forward for the entire code.

Comment: What do you mean by "going forward"?

Comment: Do you set the state to SwipeLoaded, when you loaded all the data? Don't forget to call setState() method.

Comment: Where does your state change to SwipeLoaded?

Answer (score 0):

you forget stop condition in if (state is SwipeLoading).
add some code to change your variable state and call setstate.
you will always loading if you not change variable state

Comment: Give one example please with the same code. I can't understand your point because I have already passes the swipeloaded condition.